# Vtiger 7.1 installation got stuck

Tags: php, crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

Installing vtiger 7.1 from scratch and for some reason the installation gets stuck here

[image]

Any idea why? It got stuck there for 1 hour or so...I didn't find anything on official forums that could help me. I got another vtiger 7.1 running on the same server so I got all requirements fine.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not stalled. The installation is really slow; for me on Windows 10 atop Wamp 3.1.7, it tooks ~30 minute to pass this screen, and seems to complete fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install vtiger 7.1 with these prerequisites:

- Ubuntu ubuntu-16.04.4-server-i386 (32 bit)
- Vtiger version 7.1.0
- Apache2 version 2.4.18
- MariaDB version mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.36-MariaDB
- php version 5.6

After getting this "result is not an object" I had to

1. Drop the vtiger database
2. Delete `config.ini.php`
3. Change the database like this:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE vtiger CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
   ```

And installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install vtiger 7.1.0 under with docker image [alexcomu/docker-nginx-ssh-mysql-php7](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexcomu/docker-nginx-ssh-mysql-php7/):

```
Vtiger version 7.1.0
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

More Details on the page below

https://github.com/fangj99/Vtiger-7.1.0-Installation-on-Docker/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Another image is this https://github.com/javanile/vtiger   PRO: single point of volume; suitable version; self installation; ready ssl; ready for proxy; and more...

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query in MySQL to check the installation of `State` and `Info`

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

[image: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST]